# É possível trocar o Index de um table de base de dados pelo seguinte?

Tags: php, mysql

Um tenho um tabela mysql (`tbl_test`) que tem um ID único, nome *string* e uma ordem int.

```
ID | Nome  | Ordem 
1  | name1 |  1 
2  | name2 |  4 
3  | name3 |  3 
4  | name4 |  5 
5  | name5 |  2
```

Gostava de saber se é possível ao inserir um novo novo elemento com ordem 3 passar todos os elementos a partir do antigo três um para cima. Ou seja ao inserir o `6 | name6 | 3` a tabela ficaria assim:

```
ID | Nome  | Ordem 
1  | name1 |  1 
2  | name2 |  5 
3  | name3 |  4 
4  | name4 |  6 
5  | name5 |  2
6  | name6 |  3
```

Comment: Sim, mas você precisará trabalhar com [trigger](https://www.devmedia.com.br/mysql-basico-triggers/37462) caso não queira fazer via _php_.

Comment: Realize um `update` antes de realizar o `insert`, dentro de uma transação, obviamente.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o que irá requisitar um querry dentro por cada elemento que ficar muito lento se tiver muitos elementos, obrigado de qualquer das formas.

Comment: @rLinhares não tenho problema em fazer em php mas vou dar uma olhadela ao trigger obrigado

Comment: Será apenas mais uma query, não uma para cada, mas sim, a solunção será O(N) e crescerá com o número de registros, mas nenhuma outra solução será diferente disso.

Comment: Não recomendaria usar trigger, melhor fazer no php, trigger vai ser mais rápido de implementa agora mas ao longo prazo vai te dar mais trabalho.

Comment: Executando uma query assim "update tbl_test set ordem = order+1 where ordem >= ordem_do_elemento_a_inserir" antes de inserir o novo elemento já bastaria.